# ElasticsearchRestTemplate can't save multiple documents to different index

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a test domain class

```
public class TestDocument {

    private final String id;

    private final String strField;

    private final Integer intField;

    public TestDocument(final String id, final String strField, final Integer intField) {
        this.id = id;
        this.strField = strField;
        this.intField = intField;
    }


}
```

now I invoke `ElasticsearchRestTemplate.save` method with 3 documents and want to save into 3 different indices.

```
@Service
public class TestEsService {

    @Autowired
    private ElasticsearchRestTemplate elasticsearchRestTemplate;

    @PostConstruct
    public void testSave() {
        final TestDocument d1 = new TestDocument("id_1", "str1", 1);
        final TestDocument d2 = new TestDocument("id_2", "str2", 2);
        final TestDocument d3 = new TestDocument("id_3", "str3", 3);

        this.save(List.of(d1, d2, d3));
    }

    public void save(final List<TestDocument> documents) {

        final IndexCoordinates indexCoordinates = IndexCoordinates.of("index_1", "index_2", "index_3");
       
        this.elasticsearchRestTemplate.save(documents, indexCoordinates);

    }

}
```

After executed above code. I check my local elasticsearch.
`curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?pretty' -s`

I got only one index in my ES.
`yellow open index_1 17ppJ9vJRUGIVHYBKKxXog 1 1 3 0 5.5kb 5.5kb`

and check the data of this `index_1` index:

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/index_1/_search?pretty'
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 3,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index_1",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "id_1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "_class" : "com.test.entity.TestDocument",
          "id" : "id_1",
          "strField" : "str1",
          "intField" : 1
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index_1",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "id_2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "_class" : "com.test.entity.TestDocument",
          "id" : "id_2",
          "strField" : "str2",
          "intField" : 2
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index_1",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "id_3",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "_class" : "com.test.entity.TestDocument",
          "id" : "id_3",
          "strField" : "str3",
          "intField" : 3
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

after dive into the code:

I found a clue within `RequestFactory.bulkRequest`:

```
queries.forEach(query -> {

            if (query instanceof IndexQuery) {
                bulkRequest.add(indexRequest((IndexQuery) query, index));
            } else if (query instanceof UpdateQuery) {
                bulkRequest.add(updateRequest((UpdateQuery) query, index));
            }
        });
```

actually `IndexRequest()` gets index name via `index.getIndexName();` method:

```
public IndexRequest indexRequest(IndexQuery query, IndexCoordinates index) {

        String indexName = index.getIndexName();
        IndexRequest indexRequest;
```

where `IndexCoordinates.getIndexName()` return the first index name only.

```
    public String getIndexName() {
        return indexNames[0];
    }
```

Is it a bug? Should I report to spring-data-elasticsearch Github issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple names in `IndexCoordinates` are used when accessing an Elasticsearch API that uses multiple index names, for example when searching data in multiple indices, but not for writing access.

If you want to save the 3 entities to 3 indices, you need 3 calls with different `IndexCoordinates` - each of these having one index name.

Comment: Thank you Meisch! I think it should be an improvement to achieve saving multiple indices stuff.